# Shell conditional in makefile

Tags: makefile, sh

Cant get this to work , tried everything for the conditional [] bash brackets quotes etc

The   if  $$? != "0"  never matches but the $$? is non zero at times. Any ideas ?

```
test: testdrivers
-@rc=0; \
   for file in $(TSTFILES); do  \
     ./$$file; \
     if  $$? != "0" ; then  \
     echo test fail;\
                 rc=`expr $$rc + 1` ;\
     fi \
    done; \
  echo; echo "Tests failed: $$rc"
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The right syntax for a numeric comparison in shell scripting is:

```
if [ $$? -ne 0 ]; then
```

Be *sure* you have spaces BEFORE *and* AFTER the square brackets.  They cannot be in the same word as the arguments.

Also you're missing a semicolon after the `fi`:

```
    fi; \
done; \
```

Comment: I'd probably say something like "on both sides of the opening square bracket and before the closing one" instead since `];`, as you used, is perfectly fine. Though I'll grant that is certainly less pithy.

Comment: Wouldn't be bad to say that `[` is actually the same external program as `test` (although it is likely to be builtin in large shells). So, `man test`.

Comment: Then there's something else wrong.  The syntax I provided, based on your example, will definitely work.  What does "doesn't appear to be working" mean?  What command do you type?  What errors do you see?  Please cut and paste directly, rather than retyping, as retyping often introduces subtle changes that make the problem unresolvable by us.  Edit your question and cut and paste your makefile rule as you currently have it.

Comment: It just doesnt match the conditional , i get no errors but i can echo $rc and see it is non zero..  Maybe because its not bash and i should just call a script.

Comment: Pulled it out into a seperate script and it worked  ( which is better anyway)

Comment: I don't understand.  If the `$rc` variable is non-zero then the condition _must_ be true, because that's the only place in the script (at least as you've shown it) that that variable is ever set >0.  So what do you mean by "doesn't match the conditional", and why do you think that?  If it worked in a separate script, then you had a problem with either backslashes and semicolons, or with properly quoting variables.  If you're happy with what you have fine.  If you want to understand what you were doing wrong, please read my comment above and provide the requested detail.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Use below one as an example:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
abc=all 
all:
    @ echo $(SHELL)
    @if [ $@ == $(abc) ]; then echo hi; fi;
    @echo done
```

output will be:

```
/bin/bash
hi
done
```